# Need help on choosing OS

Tags: toshiba-satellite

I have an older Toshiba Satellite A205 S5812 laptop. What version of Ubuntu should I install. It currently has Vista 32 Home premium. It has a Pentium Dual-Core 1.6 Ghz with 2 GB of Ram and a 160 GB Hard Drive. I am looking to install over the current OS. Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: Although the duplicate link gives good advice about useful OS for older systems, it doesn't mention Ubuntu-mate, which has only just been adopted as an official Ubuntu release, your system stats fit the recommended hardware requirements here https://ubuntu-mate.org/about/

Comment: @Arronical Are you sure you looked at all the answers? If you are unhappy about the existing answer that mentions Ubuntu-Mate, feel free to add your own.

Comment: No I missed that one, cheers @user68186

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have 2gb RAM, I would suggest xubuntu (XFCE). If you want it more lightweight, you could try lubuntu with LXDE.